# Shake not rebuilding when source file changes

Tags: shake-build-system

I am using Shake to build lilypond files, which are then being put into a webpage. I tried to model my `Build.hs` after the [first example in the manual](https://shakebuild.com/manual):

```
import Development.Shake
import Development.Shake.Command
import Development.Shake.FilePath
import Development.Shake.Util

dest = "www/static"

main :: IO ()
main = shakeArgs shakeOptions{shakeFiles="_build"} $ do
  want ["www/index.html"]

  phony "clean" $ do
    putNormal "Cleaning files"
    removeFilesAfter dest ["//*"]

  "www/index.html" %> \out -> do
    fs <- getDirectoryFiles "src/lilypond" ["*.ly"]
    let pdfs = ["www/static" </> (takeBaseName sourceFile) -<.> "pdf" | sourceFile <- fs]
    need pdfs

    cmd_ "cp" "src/www/index.html" "www/index.html"

  dest <> "//*.pdf" %> \outp -> do
    let c = "src/lilypond" </> (dropDirectory1 . dropDirectory1 $ outp -<.> "ly")
    let o = dropExtension outp
    cmd_ "lilypond" "-o" [o] [c]
```

The intended behaviour is "to build the index.html file, all PDFs should be generated to `www/static` from respective `src/lilypond/*.ly` files". This works for a clean build, but editing a source `.ly` files does not trigger a rebuild and I can't figure out why. (UPDATE: editing `src/www/index.html` also does not trigger a rebuild)

Things I've tried:

- Building a single PDF via command like `shake-build www/static/muppets.pdf`. Same behaviour.
- Generating a `--profile`. Nothing jumps out to me here.
- Verbose output. Not sure what to look for here, so suspect maybe the PDF rule isn't actually depending on the `.ly` file? Saw `depends = []` in output, would have expected non empty.
- Explicit `need [c]` in the PDF rule.

I feel like there is a basic concept here I've missed :/

[Full project here.](https://github.com/xaviershay/sheets/tree/emporium)

Comment: I think you are missing a call to `need [c]` just before `cmd_ "lilypond" ...`. That will cause it to add the necessary dependency - as a general rule of thumb, before calling `cmd`, you call `need` on all the things it will use.

Comment: could have swore I tried that, but nope apparently not. Works, thank you!

Comment: Great to hear, I've promoted it to an answer so we can Q/A it out properly and for those who come here in future.

Comment: thanks for all the work you do for the community Neil  Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a call to `need [c]` just before `cmd_ "lilypond" ...`. That will cause it to add the necessary dependency - as a general rule of thumb, before calling `cmd`, you call `need` on all the things it will use.